# Nagios - HTTP WARNING: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: nagios

I am using Nagios XI. I entered following command in order to monitor `httpd` service of the remote Linux server (128.19.5.131):

`/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http -H 128.19.5.131`

It is giving me following output:

`HTTP WARNING: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a file with name `index.html` in the `/var/www/html` directory of the remote Linux machine (128.19.5.131). Restarted the HTTP service with `service httpd restart` and then executed the same command, *i.e.* :

`nagiossrv root [libexec] >/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http -H 128.19.5.131`

I got following output:

`HTTP OK HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 250 bytes in 0.001 seconds |time=0.000977s;;;0.000000 size=250B;;;0`

I do not know whether it is proper to add `index.html` file in the `/var/www/html` directory of each host to be monitored or not, but it is showing desired results in the Nagios XI console.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "monitoring" in this scenario? It sounds like you installed a complete HTTP server with no purpose but to serve an index.html file to Nagios? Is there any reason you couldn't have done a simple ping check instead?

Answer (score 10):

I solved it by executing

```
$ touch /var/www/html/index.html
$ chmod 755 /var/www/html/index.html
```

on the remote server.

Answer (score 9):

You can put a username/password and tell nagios what to expect via  `-e`. It is not a must to authorize in any case and it is also not critical to have a `WARNING`.

```
 /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http -H 128.19.5.131 -e 'HTTP' --authorization=username:password
```

**Update:**

The reason why you get `forbidden` is because you don't have any index file and directory listing is disabled. You can create a file `nagios.txt` (without putting anything in) and let nagios fetch that file instead of a directory which it is not allowed to view.

Comment: `HTTP OK HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden - 3962 bytes in 0.002 seconds |time=0.001552s;;;0.000000 size=3962B;;;0` Seeming to be a positive result, but `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` part still persists.

Comment: Maybe you have a virtual host configured and it depends on a hostname, rather than on IP ? What happens when you go via browser to the IP 128.19.5.131 (from the same network as the nagios ofc).

Comment: Nagios server (172.xx.xx.xx) is part of a different network than the target host.

Answer (score 2):

Explanation is in:

```
vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf
```

```
# 
# This configuration file enables the default "Welcome"
# page if there is no default index page present for
# the root URL.  To disable the Welcome page, comment
# out all the lines below.
#
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
#Options -Indexes                        #<----- comment out this line
#ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html   #<----- comment out this line
</LocationMatch>
```

```
$ service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line like this:

```
# 'check_http_80' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_http_80
        command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H '$HOSTADDRESS$':80 -I '$HOSTADDRESS$'
        }
```

to your **/etc/nagios-plugins/config/http.cfg** and change *check_http* for *check_http_80* in your server configuration file.

Then restart you nagios server.

Answer (score 0):

i did this and it works perfectly !! follow these commands:

```
touch /var/www/html/index.html
chmod 755 /var/www/html/index.html
systemctl nagios restart
systemctl httpd restart
```

Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

On **CentOS 8 2004** NREP client, Monitored by Nagios **Ubuntu 20.04 Server**. Use commands `touch /var/www/html/index.html`  `chmod 755 /var/www/html/index.html` The Centos 8 `/var/www/html/` directory should be populated with `index.html`. After that from Ubuntu Nagios Server run command `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 10.0.0.20 -c check_http` the results `HTTP OK:`

Answer (score -1):

*touch /var/www/html/index.html*

This just worked in my case.

Comment: Solution already mentioned in other answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/26454534/2227743